# Where should I store classes that hold "data" in my MVC4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have in my MVC application a project called Storage. Inside of that I have
the following three folders:

Helpers
Models
Services

I am considering making some static classes that look like this:

```
public static class TYPE
{
    public static string City = "07";
    public static string Street = "08";
}
```

These would provide reference look ups so as to avoid me using strings like "07" in
my code.

I would like to keep with convention so what folder name should I use for these
classes in my MVC directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the folders `Controllers`, and `Views` the MVC framework doesn't require other folder structure convention to work properly (and those mentioned can be configured).  Even the default folder `Models` can be removed and renamed.

That said, it is definitely a good idea to think about structure in a logical way.  I'd suggest something like `Constants` or `Helpers` or `Lookups` or `Infrastructure`, depending on what else might live with this code.